Euler's identity in python
I am trying to calculate the Euler's in python with the following code:
import numpy as np
import cmath
x = 0
y = 1
z=complex(x,y)

out=complex(np.e**(np.pi*z.imag))
print(out)


But what I am getting is the following (and I should get -1 or something close to it with floating point errors)
$ python code.py
(23.140692632779263+0j)


I'm not familiar with cmath, but it seems you're multiplying pi by the imaginary part of z (which is 1), instead of by i. Maybe try np.e**(np.p*z)

@CerebralFart same, but it seems to be a library of a few math functions and constants, doesn't look like using e and pi from cmath over numpy makes a difference though... both seem to have a little rounding error (1.22e-16j)

import numpy as np

x = 0
y = 1
z = complex(x, y)

out = np.exp(np.pi * z)
print(out)

The issue might be because z.imag is being used directly. Since z is a complex number, it has both real and imaginary parts. To get the imaginary part, you can directly access z.imag, but it might not give you the desired result. Instead, you should use z directly in the exponentiation.
This gives the desired output

Numpy is an unnecessary dependency for something this simple. The builtin cmath module has an exp() function and pi constant.
